# JavaScript not working on IE9 but one every other browser? What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on this little app and it works just fine in every browser I can try (I'm on a Mac) and I've tried Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari and it works.  I sent it to a co-worker (who uses a PC) and he said it works on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, but not IE9.

I had another co-worker try it and he said it works on Chrome but not on IE9.

So far, it seems to work on every browser except IE9.  Another coworker said the first time in Chrome it just refreshed the screen, then he re-entered everything and it worked fine after that even with repeated uses.

Can anyone tell what's wrong with it?  This is my first real use application so I'm sorry if the issue is obvious to everyone.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Daily Calorie Limit</title>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function Calculate() {

    var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    var inches = parseInt(document.getElementById("inches").value, 10);
    var height = (parseInt(document.getElementById("feet").value, 10) * 12) + inches;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var goal = document.getElementById("goal").value;


    if(gender=="male") 
        {
            val1 = 6.23 * weight;
            val2 = 12.7 * height;
            val3 = 6.8 * age;
            dailyDeficit = (goal * 3500) / 90;

            result = 66 + val1 + val2 - val3;

            cals = result * 1.55;
            calMax = cals - dailyDeficit;

        }
    else if (gender=="female")
        {
            val1 = 6.23 * weight;
            val2 = 4.7 * height;
            val3 = 4.7 * age;
            dailyDeficit = (goal * 3500) / 90;

            result = 655 + val1 + val2 - val3;

            cals = result * 1.55;
            calMax = cals - dailyDeficit;
        }


document.getElementById("answer").textContent = 'Your Daily Calorie Limit is: ' + calMax.toFixed(0); 

}




</script>

<form action="#">
    Gender  : <select id="gender"><option value="male">Male</option><option value="female">Female</option></select><br />
    Weight  : <input type="text" id="weight" />lbs.<br />
    Height  : <input type="text" id="feet" />ft. <input type="text" id="inches" />in.<br />
    Age     : <input type="text" id="age" /><br />
    Goal    : <select id="goal"><option value=5>Lose 5 Pounds</option><option value=10>Lose 10 Pounds</option><option value=15>Lose 15 Pounds</option><option value=20>Lose 20 Pounds</option><option value=25>Lose 25 Pounds</option></select><br />


    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Give me my Daily Calorie Limit!" onclick="Calculate()" />
</form>
<div id="answer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Having problems with IE is normal and expected. It's the worst browser on the planet. Incompetent at best, you can't expect IE to do anything right.

Comment: @RobG  Alas, I cannot because it's not happening for me (on any Mac browser).  The response I got from coworkers was just that it "didn't work" or that "nothing happened" or that "it cleared out the info entered but didn't provide an answer".  A few people posted suggestions that seemed to have gone around whatever problems IE9 was having with what I wrote, so it seems to be working properly now.  At least I and co-workers have tested it on every browser we can think of and they all work now.

Answer (score 3):

I see the following problems with your script:

1. `.textContent` is not supported in every browser.  IE uses `.innerText` instead.  It's probably easiest to use `.innerHTML` which works everywhere.
2. Your button is a submit button so the page reloads after pushing it.
3. Lots of your variables are undeclared so they are implicit globals (bad).
4. You have a `</fieldset>` tag, but no matching `<fieldset>`.

Here's a fixed and working version: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/b2DgP/

Comment: I really appreciate that you took the time to not just answer my question but notice the other problems, too.  If I could give you double helpful scores, I would.  Thanks.

Comment: 1) To the contrary, textContent DOES work everywhere. As always, it is only IE that doesn't work with it. (That is IE<9). I wish someone would think of a solution rather than dumbing down the script for IE's sake.

Comment: @Rob - How can you say `.textContent` works everywhere when it doesn't work in IE8?  One can test for the existence of both `.textContent` and `.innerText` to see which one exists and operate on that if you want, but I don't see why that's better in this case than just using `.innerHTML` which does work everywhere and is appropriate for this problem.  That's not dumbing anything down - it's picking the right tool for the job.

Comment: Your statement 1) says it's not supported in every browser when the reality is it's only unsupported in IE. I didn't mean to come across as negative toward your solution but too often I hear such statements, as well as "cross browser", when what they really mean is "It doesn't work in IE". It's a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: @Rob - it doesn't work in every browser.  I knew that from memory and didn't want to take the time to look up exactly which ones it did or didn't work in.  Yes, the culprit is the same culprit that it usually is: IE.  The point is that you can't use it without having an alternative if you want to support IE8.  FYI, to me "cross browser" means that a given piece of code works in all browsers you want to support (which generally still includes IE8 and sometimes even IE7).  It's not a statement of blame.  It's just a practical comment on whether it works everywhere you need it to work or not.

Comment: @Rob "It doesn't work in every browser" doesn't mean "It doesn't work in ANY browser", nor "It fails in all browsers". So, question is "does that script work in ALL browsers?". The answer is clearly "no", because IE is a browser (and it's quite widespread, too), whether you like it or not. Of course it's up to you to support it or not, but it won't go away just because you don't like it. Also, lacking support for IE is a major flaw for any Web Application.

Comment: I will state my point again: If the problem is IE, as it almost always is, then say so and don't pass it off as a "cross browser" problem or "doesn't work in every browser" when only one browser is causing the problem. It gives the impression such things are widely unaccepted when, in reality, it works everywhere (but IE). Quit trying to be diplomatic about that POS of a browser. @Diego nowhere did I say not to support IE.

Comment: @Rob If there were 1000 browsers and the code fails on a single one, then the code doesn't work in every browser. "Everywhere, but" is not "everywhere". It's a simple statement and it holds true. The fact that you don't like IE is irrelevant (although I don't like it either) and should be left out of StackOverflow, as it doesn't add anything to the answers that you may give (quite the opposite, I'd say). I used to hate working with IE as well, but then I simply accepted the fact that it's there, with its quirks, and I learned to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out what's wrong: you use `textContent` to set the content of a DIV. Such property is not supported by Internet Explorer (welcome to the club of IE-haters). Try replacing `textContent` with `nodeValue`, it has better cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Or somehow use textContent for the modern browsers without dumbing it down for incompetent IE.

Comment: Any good developer has to support all major browsers, which, unfortunately, include IE as well. Leaving it out because it's "incompetent" would be highly unprofessional. Not to mention that most IT-illiterate users run Internet Explorer, as they don't know about any other browser.

Comment: Didn't say anything about leaving it out. I said don't dumb it down for IE. Leave textContent in but do conditional comments, or somesuch,  for incompetent IE.

Comment: Conditional comments can be even harder to maintain, as you would have to handle each specific case separately. If there is a solution that works for all the browser, it makes sense to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given you the answer, some comments and suggestions, use what you want, ignore what you don't:

1. Form controls must have a name to be successful (i.e. to be submitted with the form)
2. XML-style markup is not required unless you are using XML or XHTML and sending documents as application/XML (extremely unlikely)
3. The language attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 4, it is removed from HTML5
4. By convention, variable names starting with a capital letter are reserved for constructors
5. Where a mathematical operation other than "+" is applied to a string, it will be converted to a number, and unary "+" can be used instead of parseInt.
6. Math.round can be used instead of toFixed(0)
7. The factors for val2, val3 and result can be made dependent on the selected sex, removing the if..else statements.
8. One option in a select element should be set as the default selected

The code can be tidied and refactored to remove redundancy:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function calculate() {
    var form   = document.forms['f0'];
    var height = form.feet.value * 12 + +form.inches.value;
    var factor = form.gender.value == 'male'? [12.7, 6.8, 66] : [4.7, 4.7, 655];

    var val1 = 6.23 * form.weight.value;
    var val2 = factor[0] * height;
    var val3 = factor[1] * form.age.value;
    var result = factor[2] + val1 + val2 - val3;

    dailyDeficit = form.goal.value * 3500 / 90;
    calMax = result * 1.55 - dailyDeficit;

    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = 'Your Daily Calorie Limit is: ' +
                                                   calMax.toFixed(0); 
}

</script>

<form action="#" id="f0">
    Gender  : <select id="gender">
               <option value="male">Male
               <option value="female">Female
              </select>
              <br>
    Weight  : <input type="text" id="weight">lbs.
              <br>
    Height  : <input type="text" id="feet">ft. <input type="text" id="inches">in.
              <br>
    Age     : <input type="text" id="age">
              <br>
    Goal    : <select id="goal">
                <option value="5">Lose 5 Pounds
                <option value="10">Lose 10 Pounds
                <option value="15">Lose 15 Pounds
                <option value="20">Lose 20 Pounds
                <option value="25">Lose 25 Pounds
              </select>
              <br>
              <input type="button" value="Give me my Daily Calorie Limit!"
                     onclick="calculate()">
</form>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Comment: This is much more beautiful than what I wrote. I particularly like defaulting the gender and putting the first three variables into an array.  I feel stupid for not coming up with it, but it's a much more elegant solution than an if/else. That said, this is so far from what I wrote, that I don't think it'd be right to use it. I'd always know that it isn't really my work and the idea is to build my first real world use app. It's one thing to get help with an idea here or there, but this is a total reworking. Still, I hope to learn from what you did here. Thanks for taking the time.